# C++ issue regarding ENUM's. The response I get is bigger than the Enum list

Tags: c++, enums, enumeration

Now I have a library that is returning me a Structure, that contains an enum.
Now, if I try to log the result, I will get this:

code:

```
VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO_FORMATTED("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD License Error: errorid=%d vmConnectionPath=%d OutOfLicense=%d Result=%d Fault=%d", error, vmConnectionPath, OutOfLicenses, eventLicense->result, eventLicense->fault);
```

What I am interested in, is the eventLicense->result, aka the "Result=%d"
This is What I get back:

```
GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD License Error: errorid=0 vmConnectionPath=1 OutOfLicense=1 Result=26 Fault=0 [ VidyoClientVcsoapThread_3, <unknown func>, app/src/main/jni/ndkVidyoSample.c:62 ]
```

As you can see, the Result is: 26.
But my Enum looks like this:

```
typedef enum VidyoClientSoapResultCode_
{
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_FAILURE,               /*!< Result is some unknown general failure */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_SUCCESS,               /*!< Result is success */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_NOT_LICENSED,          /*!< Not licensed */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_SEAT_LICENSE_EXPIRED,  /*!< Seat license expired */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_WRONG_PIN,             /*!< Wrong PIN */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_CONFERENCE_LOCKED,     /*!< Conference locked */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_ROOM_DISABLED,         /*!< Room disabled */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_GENERAL_FAULT,         /*!< General Fault */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_INVALID_ARGUMENT_FAULT,/*!< Invalid argument fault */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_MEMBER_NOT_ONLINE,     /*!< Status of member is not online */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_NOT_OWNER_OF_ROOM,     /*!< Not owner of room */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_USER_NOT_FOUND,        /*!< Specified user is not found */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_UNEXPECTED_SUBELEMENT_IN_MESSAGE,  /*!< Unexpected sub element in SOAP message */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_END_POINT_NOT_FOUND,   /*!< Endpoint not found */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_FAILED_PLACE_DIRECT_CALL, /*!< Failed to place a direct call */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_IPC_JOIN_FAILURE,      /*!< Failure to join room on other portal */
VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_ALL_LINES_IN_USE,      /*!< All lines are in use */
} VidyoClientSoapResultCode;
```

My Enum does not contain 26 items, so I do not know which error it is. How can I check this?

## EDIT:

I changed my log to show this:

```
 VidyoClientSoapResultCode result = eventLicense->result;
 VidyoClientSoapFault fault = eventLicense->fault;
 VIDYO_CLIENT_LOG_INFO_FORMATTED("GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD License Error: errorid=%d vmConnectionPath=%d OutOfLicense=%d Result=%d Fault=%d", error, vmConnectionPath, OutOfLicenses, result, fault);
```

Just to be sure that I create objects for them before logging as a decimal.
Now from what I know, for ENUM, decimal is the way to log, correct?
But still, now I get a even weirder response:

```
10-11 08:34:43.954: I/VidyoClinetLib(7103): 10-11 08:34:43.965 INFO  AppGui        GuiOnOutEvent NDKMETHOD License Error: errorid=0 vmConnectionPath=1 OutOfLicense=1 Result=21324 Fault=32 [ VidyoClientVcsoapThread_3, <unknown func>, app/src/main/jni/ndkVidyoSample.c:64 ]
```

Maybe this new data helps?
I mean 21324 looks weird, but it's consistant, now everytime at the error I get this. But it's surely not in the 0:31 like Oliv said

After seeing the comments from Demosthenes I logged all values of the ENUM, and indeed they are 0-16. (17 elements). So Still confused a bit, maybe I'm not logging correctly it?

Comment: This is a probably a bug in the library, I suppose the intent of this enumeration was to document result codes. (From a the  language point of view this is not a bug because the value is within the range of values of this enumerator [0;31])

Comment: More often than not, that means you have a version mismatch between your header and the library. The BEST course of action would be tracking down an up-to-date header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, enums are really initialized starting from 0 and increasing by 1 (unless defined explicitly). Not sure if that is required behaviour for the compiler, but on most systems it will certainly work that way.

Here's a few pointers how you could debug:

1. Define the enum values explicitly, i.e. `=0`, `=1`, etc. If you still get an out-of-bounds value, the function you are calling has a bug and indeed returns an out-of-bounds value. If not, apparently the compiler does not initialize with 0,1,...
2. Consider switching to the type-safe C++ (from C++11) variant: `enum class`. The compiler will give you an error whenever you convert between the type and int without an explicit `static_cast`, also by just using the name of an enum constant (without the namespace) you will get an error. In case there is some weird arithmetic going on, the compiler will tell you, and once you fixed all compilation errors (and if you introduce casts, thought about them), your code will likely behave correctly.

Comment: The library which provides me the response contains also the Struct for the enum. I have access only to the .h (header file). Also that library is made in c, not c++. I tried then, but did not manage the thing with the static_cast. Hence my question. And yes, I assumed it's like that, that it starts with 0 and increments. But it has 17 not 26 items. Still looking into it

Comment: This works: `VidyoClientSoapResultCode result = eventLicense->result;` But this: `int bla = VidyoClientSoapResultCode.VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_FAILURE;` gets my this issue at build: `error: unexpected type name 'VidyoClientSoapResultCode': expected expression`.
Because of that, I couldn't input the values, to check. Also please check my edit

Comment: The last comment shows that you didn't understand how enums work: Try `int bla = VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_FAILURE;` If it was a C++ enum class, it would be  `int bla = static_cast<int>(VidyoClientSoapResultCode::VIDYO_CLIENT_SOAP_RESULT_FAILURE);`. But it's a C-enum, so no namespace here.

Comment: Thanks, will do, This is NDK code for Android, and it's a bit hard to go from Android development, to c code, especially if not c++

Comment: And yes, tried firsth the static_cast, but it didn't work cause it's not c++ :(

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it made it possible for me to read the enum values, and that is what I needed. After looking into it, I found the real issue, and managed to past over, regardless of the fact that the enum was not in the bounds